# Twig-extensions in Silex

Tags: twig, silex

I try to load Twig-extensions into Silex but get a:

> 'Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text' not found

I first register Twig-Extensions in the autoloader:

```
$app['autoloader']->registerPrefixes(array( 'Twig_'  => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/Twig-extensions/fabpot/lib')));
```

Then register Twig:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
        'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/../views',
         'twig.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/twig/lib',
));
```

and add the Extension.

```
$oldTwigConfiguration = isset($app['twig.configure']) ? $app['twig.configure']: function(){};
$app['twig.configure'] = $app->protect(function($twig) use ($oldTwigConfiguration) {
    $oldTwigConfiguration($twig);
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text());
});
```

Pathes seem to be correct and Twig itself works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: It works without the underscore at Twig:

    $app['autoloader']->registerPrefixes(array( 'Twig'  => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/Twig-extensions/fabpot/lib')));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. PEAR-convention autoload mappings are defined as "prefix" => "path". You are setting the "Twig_" prefix for the twig extensions, then you register the twig service provider, which will override it, pointing to twig itself.

The solution is to use a prefix other than "Twig_", preferably something more specific. Something like "Twig_Extensions_".

```
$app['autoloader']->registerPrefix('Twig_Extensions_', __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig-extensions/lib');
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 7):

In Silex 1.3 you can use the *new* `extend` method of Pimple:

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
    $twig->addExtension(new \My\Twig\Extension\SomeExtension($app));
    return $twig;
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Silex 2.0, first [register the TwigServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/twig.html#registering):

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));
```

Then use [Twig Customization path](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/twig.html#customization)

> You can configure the Twig environment before using it by extending the `twig` service

and [Twig Extensions installation guide](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/text.html#installation):

```
$app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text());
    return $twig;
});
```